# Is it possible to select a Paragraph in the Table Row data using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, select, paragraph

I have data in a table row that is "separated" by paragraphs. I need to select and display the data in each paragraph separately.

```
<p>1 The Turtle is slow. </p>
<p>2 The Rabbit is fast. </p>
<p>3 The Horse eats hay. </p>
```

Is it even possible to do this? If not, is there any other possible way that I can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substring_index()` to basically do this.

If you want the first paragraph:

```
select replace(substring_index(col, '</p>', 1), '<p>', '')
```

For the second:

```
select replace(substring_index(substring_index(col, '</p>', 2), '</p>', -1), '<p>', '')
```